# Salesforce1 not showing visualforce page on dashboard

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, dashboard

[image: The problem looks like this]
The problem looks like this image.

I have followed the instructions:

> Visualforce pages that use the Standard Controller can’t be used in dashboards. To be included in a dashboard, a Visualforce page must have either no controller, use a custom controller, or reference a page bound to the StandardSetController Class. If a Visualforce page does not meet these requirements, it does not appear as an option in the dashboard component Visualforce Page drop-down list.

I have used custom controller with the pages to be shown on the dashboard but the dashboard shows Visualforce components aren't available.

I have marked the pages to be used for Salesforce1 any thing else i am missing ?Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using any of the components listed here (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/Content/vf_dev_best_practices_components_unsupported.htm) as being not supported in Salesforce1?

Comment: I am fetching data and showing it using Page Block Table only.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an undocumented restriction on dashboards in the Salesforce1 application to me. Even Visualforce pages with no controller and a couple of lines of HTML markup produce the same error message for both the installed iOS app and when accessing via the Safari browser.

There doesn't appear to be a known issue for this, or an anything on the idea exchange, so you are probably best raising it with support.

Comment: I am not able to raise case from my developer account.I have posted this as an idea on idea exchange https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4QMAAY

Comment: I've voted for the idea.